# Error 1004 on while loop while switching sheets vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm pretty new to vba, and have only been learning it for about a month for work. I keep having this problem where I get the Error 1004 "Application defined, or object defined error" when I try to run my macro. What I'm trying to do is to go through a list of data, and find out if a row has a specific code attached to it. If it does I want to move a date on that row to a new sheet.

```
Sub k0Pop()

Dim source As Long
Dim servR As Integer
Dim servC As Integer
Dim patID As Integer
Dim spot1 As Integer
Dim spot2 As Integer

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet4")

servR = 3

For source = 3 To 100000
    servC = 2
    While sht2.Cells(source, 2) < sht2.Cells(patID, 15)
        source = source + 1
    Wend

    While Cells(source, 2) = Cells((source + 1), 2)
        If Cells(source, 6) = "K045A" Then
            spot = source
        End If
        source = source + 1
    Wend

    If Cells(source, 6) = "K045A" Then
        spot = source
        source = source + 1
    End If

    spot2 = source
    source = spot1

    While (Cells(spot, 5) - Cells(source, 5)) < 365
        source = source - 1
    Wend

    While source < spot
        sht1.Cells(servR, servC) = sht2.Cells(source, 5)
        source = source + 1
        servC = servC + 1
    Wend

    sht1.Cells(servR, 14) = sht2.Cells(spot, 5)

    source = spot2
    servR = servR + 1
    patID = patID + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: On what line is the error?

Comment: you sometimes forget to reference the sheet from wich cells are in. also use option explicit, you use a variable spot (wich might be spot1 ?)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like patID is 0, which is an invalid column.  Use F8 to single cycle.  Hover over a variable to see its value.  Use debug.print's to show intermediate data.